# How To Add a Previously Posted Picture to a Brand New Tweet (Twitter)

Tags: images, upload, twitter

If you wish to re-post a picture on Facebook you just write a post and attach an image from your photos gallery. On Twitter there doesn't seem to be any way of doing this?

Is it not possible to do a new tweet and attach a previously uploaded photo? At the moment I just re-upload the photo, which seems a bit of a waste to be honest.

Kind regards,

Emily.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has its own photo/video gallery, it is called [Twitter Media Studio](https://studio.twitter.com/library). You can access it here:

[**`https://studio.twitter.com/library`**](https://studio.twitter.com/library)

There, you'll find all the images and videos you ever twitted in the past and an easy way to include them in new tweets.

Comment: Did the twitter studio solve your problem?